# Cocos2d-X Menu Callback Throws Exception

Tags: c++, callback, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am currently migrating my software from Cocos2d-X 2.2.6 to Cocos2d-X 3.10 and I am having trouble to make some MenuItem callbacks work.

My code is below:

```
bool MainMenuLayer::init()
{
    bool result;

    result = Layer::init();

    mainMenu = Menu::create();
    mainMenu->setPosition(0, 0);
    this->addChild(mainMenu);

    Sprite *equalSprite, *equalDownSprite;
    MenuItemSprite *equalButton;
    LabelBMFont *equalButtonLabel;
    MenuItemLabel *equalButtonMenuLabel;
    CCPoint equalButtonMenuLabelPosition;
    CCPoint equalButtonPosition;

    equalSprite = Sprite::createWithSpriteFrameName("botao_menu_igual.png");
    equalDownSprite = Sprite::createWithSpriteFrameName("botao_menu_igual_down.png");

    equalButton = MenuItemSprite::create(equalSprite, equalDownSprite, CC_CALLBACK_1(MainMenuLayer::buttonPressedCallback, this));

    equalButton->setEnabled(gameContext->getEqualGameEnabled());
    equalButton->setTag(EQUAL_BUTTON_TAG);
    equalButtonPosition = Point(screenSize.width / 4, screenSize.height / 2);
    equalButton->setPosition(mainMenu->convertToNodeSpace(equalButtonPosition));

    mainMenu->addChild(equalButton);

    equalButtonLabel = LabelBMFont::create(localization->getLocalizedString("EqualButtonLabel"), fontHelper->getStdFont().c_str());
    equalButtonMenuLabel = MenuItemLabel::create(equalButtonLabel, CC_CALLBACK_1(MainMenuLayer::buttonPressedCallback, this));

    equalButtonMenuLabel->setTag(EQUAL_BUTTON_TAG);
    equalButtonMenuLabelPosition.x = equalButtonPosition.x;
    equalButtonMenuLabelPosition.y = equalButtonPosition.y - equalButton->boundingBox().size.height / 2 - equalButtonMenuLabel->boundingBox().size.height;
    equalButtonMenuLabel->setPosition(mainMenu->convertToNodeSpace(equalButtonMenuLabelPosition));

    mainMenu->addChild(equalButtonMenuLabel);
```

Also here is a part of the header file in which I define the mainMenu object:

```
using namespace cocos2d;

class MainMenuLayer : public Layer
{

private:

    Size screenSize;

    Menu *mainMenu;

    bool init();

    void buttonPressedCallback(Ref *sender);

public:

    MainMenuLayer();

    ~MainMenuLayer();

    static MainMenuLayer *create();

    static CCScene *scene();

};
```

The problem is that when I run my game, and click on the buttons created above, I get an exception on the file type_traits file, and in the: `return (((*_STD forward<_Ty1>(_Arg1)).*_Pmf)(_STD forward<_Types2>(_Args2)...));` line (see below).

```
    struct _Invoker_pmf_pointer
    {    // INVOKE a pointer to member function on a [smart] pointer
    template<class _Decayed,
        class _Ty1,
        class... _Types2>
        static auto _Call(_Decayed _Pmf, _Ty1&& _Arg1, _Types2&&... _Args2)
        -> decltype(((*_STD forward<_Ty1>(_Arg1)).*_Pmf)(
            _STD forward<_Types2>(_Args2)...))
        {    // INVOKE a pointer to member function on a [smart] pointer
        return (((*_STD forward<_Ty1>(_Arg1)).*_Pmf)(
            _STD forward<_Types2>(_Args2)...));
        }
    };
```

I am creating this callback wrong? Has anyone else encountered this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the error was. The problem was that I was registering a touch listener on a previous scene and I wasn't removing it when the scene ended.

So when I added the remove touch listener code before changing scenes, everything worked well.

```
void SplashScreenMenuLayer::onTouchesEnded(Touch* touch, Event* event)
{
    Director::getInstance()->getEventDispatcher()->removeEventListener(touchListener);
    Director::getInstance()->replaceScene(MainMenuLayer::scene());
}
```